# Is the primary IP address of a PostgreSQL Google Cloud SQL instance permanent?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

The *MySQL* (not PostgreSQL) [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#appaccessIP) mentions that instances have a *static* IPv4 address automatically assigned. But does the same apply to *PostgreSQL* and is a *static* IP address also *permanent*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct.

PostgreSQL instances exist only as 2nd gen flavor, which means there is no support for IPv6 connectivity for it yet.

Instance IP address remains associated with it throughout its entire lifetime. (i.e. restarts, maintenance, failover, etc. won't cause a change of instance IP address.)

Comment: @mritz_p: yes, it is. Instance IP address remains associated with it throughout its entire lifetime: restarts, maintenance, failover, etc. won't cause change of instance IP address.